# Check if picture password is activated in Windows 8

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8

I need to write a script that verifies that the user **is not** using the ["Picture Password" feature in Windows 8](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/picture-passwords). I'm using .NET 4.

I tried to search for info about it, but couldn't find anything. Do you have any clue how it can be done?

Comment: Why do you need to check this?

Comment: maybe it is marked in the registry. [Here](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/activate-deactivate-picture-password-sign-in-windows-8) are some hints how to disable it. Maybe you can try to record your registry changes while changing the logon type.

Comment: Lasse, my company information securiy forbids using picture password when using other specific product (can`t give more info). I need to enforce this request by code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> my company information securiy forbids using picture password when using other specific product (can`t give more info). I need to enforce this request by code.

You don't enforce these kinds of things with code, you enforce them with Group Policies.

To do so, open the Group Policy editor (`gpedit.msc`) and navigate to the following path:

```
Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Logon
```

Double-click the **"Turn off picture password sign-in"** setting, and set either the "Enabled" or "Disabled" option.

Of course, you don't have to do this on each local machine. You can create Group Policies that apply network-wide to specific groups of users. Ask on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) to get more help on setting that up, or talk to your network administrator. Presumably if you have information security policies, you already have a department that handles these sorts of things.

Comment: Cody, Thanks for your answer. I can`t use group policies because this requirement intended to unmanaged machines - my script will run on machines that I don`t know anything about them (not company machines). The only tool I have is just this script. (my question is just about single test but there are dozens more)

Comment: Is this a script that needs to do this, or does it need to be in code? Is the script really an application, and is it a Windows 8 Store app?

Comment: I`m not sure if script is the right term.
Its Console application. Its for regular desktop app not win 8

Answer (score 3):

I see that you have Windows-RT as a keyword on the question. So if the application needs to do the checking is a Windows 8 Store app (Modern/Metro app), you will not be able to achieve this.

1. There is no API to check for this in 8, and as far as I know there isn't one in 8.1 either.
2. There is no access to the registry for Store apps.

Even if you did manage a way to detect the settings via some other method, you need to ensure it's done through the Windows 8 API otherwise you won't pass certification ([section 3.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694083.aspx)).

You can however push the policy [via GPO](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/activate-deactivate-picture-password-sign-in-windows-8) if that's an option.

---

Based on Windows 8 RT being removed from keywords, that means it's not a Windows 8 Store app. Leaving prior answer in case someone finds this and is asking about Store apps.

---

You should be able to review the setting via the registry at "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System" and checking the value of either BlockDomainPicturePassword or AllowDomainPicturePassword.

I don't know why there is two, I'll leave the testing to you as to which one is the right one.

Comment: invenetix, its not for Windows 8 modern UI app. I wrote this tag by mistake - fixing it now. sorry.